# Button прикрепление изображения

Tags: java, android, изображения, button

Как через код прикрепить к Button изображение в правую часть кнопки?

Comment: Что значит "через Activity"? Возможно имеется в виду не через XML а менять эту картинку из кода - программно?

Comment: @anber да именно это и имеется в виду

Answer (score 3):

Есть стандартные свойсва у кнопки

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/kitchen"
```

Это пример установления картинки на кнопке слева. справа думаю сами догодаетесь как сделать.

Вот полный код одной такой кнопки

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Кухня"
        android:id="@+id/buttonKitchen"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/kitchen"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 2):

у любого `View` есть метод `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

Например, чтобы поставить картинку справа:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon, 0);
```

Comment: большое спасибо , выручили

Comment: @Дмитрий если помогло отметьте ответ как правильный - там слева от текста есть галочка